# How can I retrieve my Custom User Attributes (Claims) from B2C using Graph API?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, token, azure-ad-b2c, claims

I have successfully created an application that uses a new B2C Tenant for authentication and I can login and call APIs.

I have added new Attributes for the Users (Roles one of them).
In my "User Flows" I have 1 flow for SignIn that has selected the Roles claim one to login and one to edit users. In the following images you can see the setup and the returned claims, after editing with the User Flow.

[Added extended user attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zcRh.png)

[Selected to return data as claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzwDh.png)

[Decoded Token with extension claims and values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSxVg.png)

However, when I query Graph PI for the users + extensions, the extensions are not returned.

I have also access to the users using Graph API and I'm able to add extensions to the users by code using the Graph API. I can Add extended attributes, update them, retrieve them...
In the code below I can Add them. These created with the Graph API I can retrieve later, but not the ones that I created with the B2C User Flow.

```
    // Add extension without the guid from b2c_extensions_app        
    var extension = new OpenTypeExtension()
    {
        ExtensionName = $"extension_Roles",
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Roles", value}
        }
    };
    await _graphServiceUsers[userId].Extensions.Request().AddAsync(extension);


    // Add extension with the guid from b2c_extensions_app  
    var extension2= new OpenTypeExtension()
    {
        ExtensionName = $"extension_00000000-e062-0000-8ec8-800000000003_Roles",
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Roles", value}
        }
    };

    await _graphServiceUsers[userId].Extensions.Request().AddAsync(extension2);
```

Neither of the scenarios above are linked to the B2C User that is returned with the claims.

I can retrieve the user with the extensions with the following code. And I get the extensions created from Graph API, but not the ones that are shown in the claims of the Token in the images above.

```
_graphServiceUsers[userId].Request().Select(UserSelectExpression).Expand("extensions").GetAsync();
```

All the custom attributes seem to be disconnected. I would need to update the ones that are returned as Claims, as they are the ones that I want to modify with the Graph API.

If you see the image below, you can see how the Extended properties are coming, but not the ones that I added from B2C. In the token you can see the mapped claim having one value, different from the value I added and retrieved from Graph API.

[Different values from Claims and retrieved data using Graph API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0VP3.png)

I think they just made it too difficult, when it reality should be a lot easier to achieve something as simple as adding a new attribute and retrieve the values and work with them using Graph API.

---

### Additional Info:

I'm using the Graph API application to access using the api

[B2C Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JWbX.png)

I added all the permissions that had been suggested

[Graph API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc0G6.png)

In Graph Explorer (same results as C#):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/600001c5-0000-49b9-89c5-0000c80000fc?$select=displayName,identities,extension_39b4801c-5782-48d4-be6a-1cae6a8a881a_Roles
```

Result (Exception):
[Result Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDi1M.png)

[Result C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTPTx.png)

----------- UPDATE WITH SOLUTION --------------

I just wanted to add a quick note to clarify that the real problem, just in case someone has the same problem, as it's a bit complicated to get started with Graph API.

The problem (as of today) is that you need to use the Beta version of the Nuget packages or the Beta (graph.microsoft.com/beta) graph api to retrieve all the extension attributes. The stable version doesn't work.

1. The nuget package that worked for me is Microsoft.Graph.Beta 4.21.0-preview.
2. The package Microsoft.Graph stable 4.11.0 published Nov 25 2021 doesn't retrieve the extension properties.

Note: Something that is important is that the extension extension_39b0000c570000d4be6a1cae7a9a000a_Roles doesn't have the - from the guid.

- Use this 39b0000c570000d4be6a1cae7a9a000a
- and not this 39b0000-c570-000d-4be6a1-cae7a9a000a (remove the dashes)

Also, an additional thing to remember is the use of the guid from the extension to load only the extension:
The first one to load all the attributes for the user.
The second one to load only the Custom extended attribute.

```
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync();
    
    
    var user2 = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().Select("id,extension_39b0000c570000d4be6a1cae7a9a000a_Roles").GetAsync();
```

Comment: Only Graph API **beta** endpoint returns extension attributes.

Comment: I have tried with version 1.0 and it returns the extension attributes, but they seem to be different to the ones defined in B2C. Using the Graph API I get the ones created by the graph api, using B2C user flows it gets only the onesfrom the flows

Comment: I think that you are right Jas, using the Beta it returns the values. Using the v1.0 seems to be disconnected from the other properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my test, I can use this request to get extension properity:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/198axxxxx9ce1c?$select=id,country,extension_3d3xxxxx707e_tiny_custom_prop
```

test result is

[image]

And with asp.net core code, following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-2):

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "b2c_tenant_id_here";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "application_clientid_that_registered_in_b2c";
var clientSecret = "app_client_secret";
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = graphClient.Users["198xxxxx9ce1c"].Request()
                    .Select("id,country,extension_3dxxxxx7e_tiny_custom_prop")
                    .GetAsync();
var res = user.Result;
```

[image]

===========================Update============================

You can see the claim is also a custom properity, and I got the value of this property of my specific user. The user I queried here is one which I signed up when redirect to the b2c sign up page, and the user flow is required to set this custom property.

[image]

I created an azure ad b2c application and set these api permission for this app.

[image]
[image]

I used v1.0 version in my workaround, so I need to use $select feature to get extension property in my code, but if I used beta version here, I can get extension property directly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried and I get an exception doing it that way. I can add the extended property in the list of properties to return but nothing happens. If I add the guid inside the property it throws an exception. I have edited my question to add the additional information with the results comparing graph API results with Claims from token returned by B2C. They just make it too complicated.

Comment: @Roberto I added more details about my test, and as you mentioned you `got an exception`, could you pls show us your exception message? I think my scenario should be similar to you, have a custom property in azure ad b2c user flow, and wanna use graph api to get the value of that property for a specific user.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I've followed your steps and I get the exception. I have updated my question with the additional images and calls and Exceptions received. Most likely is something dumb that I've missed, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Roberto Hi, according your update, my suggestion is , you can test calling your api via `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/600001c5-0000-49b9-89c5-0000c80000fc` first, pls note using beta version here so that all the property will display in the result. And you can check if there's the property of `extension_xxx_xxx` in that user. If the property really exists, you may need to only `.Select("extension_xxx_xxx")` in your code to see if it worked.

Comment: @Roberto For me, if I use beta version to call the api to get user profile data, I can see the extension property in the api response.

Comment: I have managed to get it working using the Beta Packages. I think that that was the problem, I was using the v1.0. I had to uninstall the nuget package and install the Beta. Now that I can retrieve the data, I need to Update it, but I hope that is a lot easier. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to see you got the correct response, and exactly both v1.0 and beta are worked in my side. Thanks for your response sir : )

Comment: After further investigation, the exception parsing the property was due to the - (dashes) from the GUID. It seems that you have to remove the dashes and then it works to select only one property. I have updated the Issue with additional information about the correct use of the Graph API for other people not to have the same issue.

Comment: It's really kind of you sir.

Comment: I have tried every suggestion throughout this post to include trying to use the beta version, but have not been able to access any of my custom user attribute for my b2c user.  I am using graph client 5.34.0 and .net core 7.  and C#.  I am not able to use the select or request method as they are not recognized, but some examples here follow what I can.   Really need some help as I am managing access after signup with custom roles attribute.

Comment: @Tory Crowe, Hi, I'm afraid you might firstly test the api  via tools like postman to see if the graph api could return the properties you wanna get, and then troubleshoot in  the SDK.

Comment: @TinyWang thank you for the response.  I have tried all the suggestions here.  I have even built the queries in the graph explorer.  It will not pull them back.  I get them as claims, but I don't want some attributes accessible in their profile so I want to set them behind the scenes.  Anyway, I see that you have accomplished this, but have you lately?  Are you still able to retrieve custom attributes with current libraries?  I am wondering if changes have broken your ability to as well or if I am missing something.

Comment: @TinyWang. Thank you for your response earlier.  I wanted to follow up with you because of the few questions I provided in my last post.  I have figured out my issue.  I am getting the values and this set of instructions actually did help.  I determined that I was actually using the wrong userId for the account I am logged in with.  This was easy to do because I have two accounts with the same information because of my testing and microsoft created another for me due to there two factor requirment updates.  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a quick note to clarify that the real problem, just in case someone has the same problem, as it's a bit complicated to get started with Graph API.

The problem (as of today) is that you need to use the Beta version of the Nuget packages or the Beta (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta) graph api to retrieve all the extension attributes. The stable version doesn't work.

1. The nuget package that worked for me is Microsoft.Graph.Beta 4.21.0-preview.
2. The package Microsoft.Graph stable 4.11.0 published Nov 25 2021 doesn't retrieve the extension properties.

Answer (score 0):

I could access custom properties using the standard .NET SDK for Microsoft.Graph API (not beta) in late 2022.  I found the trick was to specify the property in the select clause.

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
    .Select($"extension_{b2cExtensionsAppClientId}_Roles")
    .GetAsync();
```

The other trick was to get the Application (Client) Id of the b2c extensions app for including in the select clause.  I could get this by navigating to App Registrations in the Azure Portal and clicking 'All Applications'.  There I was shown the b2c-extensions-app where I could retrieve the app Id.

Answer (score 0):

`Graph.Client` v5 request to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` endpoint looks like this in C#:

```
        var phoneNumberClaim = $"extension_{b2cClientId}_PhoneNumber";
        var graphResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Users[request.UserId].GetAsync(options =>
        {
            options.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "identities", phoneNumberClaim };
        }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        var user = new GetUserResponse.UserItem
        {
            FullName = graphResponse!.DisplayName!,
            Email = graphResponse.Identities!.First(i => i.SignInType == "emailAddress").IssuerAssignedId!,
            PhoneNumber = graphResponse.AdditionalData[phoneNumberClaim]?.ToString(),
        };

        var response = new GetUserResponse
        {
            User = user
        };

        return response;
```

If you're testing it out using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), make sure you're signed into the b2c tenant with a user. If you're in the wrong tenant, sign out and then append `?tenantId={tenantId}` onto the url (i.e. `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com`).

Example raw graph request on the graph explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/61000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000f297?$select=id,displayname,extension_480000000000000000000000000000a6_PhoneNumber,identities
```

Where the first id is the user object id and the extension id is the client id of the b2c application registration (**not your application registration client id!** - starts with `b2c-extensions-app`). For example, I had a Phone Number attribute.

Permissions I had on my application registration (not the b2c one) were as follows:

- Directory.Read.All
- Application.Read.All